# Changing Numbers In the Same ln and col

Tags: python

I have been trying for a while now to find a way on python to move from 1 to 9 on the same Line and Column.

I want the output like this: 1 then it well clear of the screen then it will print 2 in the same place as 1.

Is this Even possible??

P.S. I am a noob a python.

Comment: Anything is possible. Could you clarify what you want to know?

Comment: Line and Column of what?

Answer (score 0):

If you cannot use a more advanced mechanism like [ANSI escape codes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code) to control cursor positioning, you can always fake it using ASCII backspaces and/or carriage returns. A backspace (`\b`) will go back one position on the same line, and a carriage return (`\r`) will return to the beginning of the line.

The following code snippet will output the numbers from 1 through 9, with half a second of pause in between:

```
import sys
from time import sleep

for i in range(1, 10):
    print '{0}\r'.format(i),
    sys.stdout.flush() # manual flush because we aren't writing newlines
    sleep(.5)
```

The [`curses`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/curses.html) module provides more advanced mechanisms for positioning if you need them.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean just like what we see when downloading and installing a package? a percentage changing without position move on the line?

Try something like this：

```
import sys
import time
for i in range(1,10):
    sys.stdout.write('%d\r' %i)
    sys.stdout.flush()
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thanks. but still not what I'm looking for. I that moves to the right i want it to not move at all.

Comment: I tried this code in my centos 6. And the number doesn't move...It is always displayed on the same position. I think I need to try it on mac to see if there is anything different....